# Using JSF h:outputLink to produce a page anchor

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, anchor

Simple question:

How do you create an HTML anchor like

```
<a id="organization" />
```

with **JSF**, e.g.

```
<h:outputLink ... />
```

or another JSF link component? **Is it possible at all?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *could* use [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) for that. Its `id` attribute becomes the `<a id>` and `<a name>`.

```
<h:link id="organization" value="Organization" fragment="organization" />
```

It generates the following HTML:

```
<a id="organization" name="organization" href="/currentcontext/currentpage.xhtml#organization">Organization</a>
```

But just using plain `<a>` or even `<span>` or `<div>` is perfectly legal in JSF/HTML as jump targets.

```
<span id="organization">Organization</span>
```

In order to create a link which jumps to that, use `<h:link fragment>` without `id`:

```
<h:link value="Jump to organization" fragment="organization" />
```

The generated HTML will look like this:

```
<a href="/currentcontext/currentpage.xhtml#organization">Jump to organization</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
<h:outputLink value="www.yourweb/somePage#anchor" />
```

or if its on the same page just

```
<h:outputLink value="#anchor" />
```

Comment: Because this will produce the links leading to the anchors, but not the anchors themselves? This was actually the point of this question... ;-)

Comment: I don't think so, why cant you use `<a id="organization" />` syntax?It is perfectly ok to do that...

Comment: I can use that - sure, but that was not the question. I'm interested to know even though a solution is already present.

Comment: the previous answer is the solution. This code doesnt generate #anchor, just generated normal link without anchor.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h:link value="test" outcome="icerik">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{icerik.id}" />
</h:link>
```

This links to `icerik.xhtml?id=2` and seems like `<a href="icerik.xhtml.?id=2">test</a>`